# How to create a custom chainable delay function in JavaScript using prototype, IIFE, currying or using new keyword

Tags: javascript, prototype, currying, iife, prototype-chain

How can I create a custom chainable delay function in JavaScript using prototype or currying or using new keyword?

Original question is

```
var foo = function () {
    console.log("bingo!");
};

function bar() {
    console.log("Wow!");
}
// make below two lines work
foo.delay(300); // after 0.3s: "bingo!"
bar.delay(600); // after 0.6s: "Wow!"
// This returns undefined, how to fix it?
```

My attempt so far.

```
function delay(time) {
    setTimeout(this, time);
}

var foo = (function () {
    console.log();
    console.log("bingo!");
    return {
      delay: delay.bind(this)
    }
})();

function bar() {
     console.log("Wow!");
    return {
      delay: delay.bind(this)
    }
};

// bar.prototype.delay = function() { return console.log("bar.prototype.delay"); }
foo.delay(300); // after 0.3s: "bingo!"
bar.delay(600); // after 0.6s: "Wow!"
```

Lastly, can I ask you where would be a good place to study these kind of topics to be more fluent in JavaScript? Thank you in advance.

Comment: What are you planning to do with this function? Do you want to chain other methods to it? Or you just need a delay to insert in between other function calls?

Comment: Btw, you code return Unexpected identifier error after the delay. Why are you calling the function bound to `this` in setTimeout?

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with this code:

```
setTimeout(this, time); // The first param must be the function to be executed after `n` ms.
```

Here you need to pass the `time` value to the function `delay`, you could pass the implicit `arguments`array.

```
return {
  delay: delay.bind(this) // Here you need to pass the `time` value.
}
```

This is an approach to bind the `delay` function.

```
return {
    delay: delay.bind(this, function() {
        console.log("Wow!");
    }, ...arguments)
}
```

**Important:** You don't to bind the function `delay` to pass the context `this` value.  That binding it's necessary if the function `delay` will use the context `this`.

```js
function delay(fn, time) {
  setTimeout(fn, time);
}

var foo = (function() {
  return {
    delay: delay.bind(this, function() {
      console.log("bingo!");
    }, ...arguments)
  };
})();

var bar = (function() {
  return {
    delay: delay.bind(this, function() {
      console.log("Wow!");
    }, ...arguments)
  };
})();

// bar.prototype.delay = function() { return console.log("bar.prototype.delay"); }
foo.delay(300); // after 0.3s: "bingo!"
bar.delay(600); // after 0.6s: "Wow!"
```